# Instagram Token

Tags: instagram, token, instagram-api

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить токен инстаграма без oauth?

По прямой ссылке с логином и паролем.

Comment: По прямой ссылке кажется нельзя. А в чем проблема использовать oauth?

Comment: Должно быть, некоторые ребята используют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

[Instagram Private API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)